# I need a regex that return non emails from a string

Tags: php, regex

After a lot of searching I found this regex that finds emails inside a string:

```
preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i", $text, $output);
```

How can I have the exact oposite effect? I really need to know what are the words that aren't a valid email address :-)

Comment: good post about email-verification http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html The amount of non-valid-words are infinite!

Comment: @Fredrik but aren't there a finite amount of words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I have the exact oposite effect? I really need to know what are the words that aren't a valid email address :-)

If the mentioned regular expression works sufficiently for you, use preg_replace to filter out the matches, the remaining text will be everything that isn't what matched:

```
<?php
$text = 'Your text here.';

// replace everything that matches with ''.
$text = preg_replace( "/^[^a-z0-9]+([^_\.-][^a-z0-9]+)^@([^a-z0-9]+([^.-][^a-z0-9]+))+\.[a-z]{2,}/i", '', $text );

echo $text;
```

Comment: <code>$text = "asdfasfd asdf test@test.com 123123 sdf 123test@test.com";
preg_replace( "/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i", "", $text );
echo "<br>non mails > $text";
</code>
Doesn't work right.

Comment: @Demon_athens That's why I said "*If the mentioned regular expression works sufficiently for you*." I'm well aware there's no regular expression that can actually filter out e-mail addresses, but if that works for his text, who am I to argue?

Comment: Well actually the preg_match_all command works great. The same thing with preg_replace is not working, so I guess I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: @Demon_athens Ah I see, I misunderstood you, sorry. It's because preg_replace returns the replaced text, it doesn't replace by reference. So just do $text = preg_replace( ) as per the updated example, that should fix the issue.

Comment: @Demon_athens You're not stupid, it's an oversight I've made myself just as well. That happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `preg_replace($pattern, "", $string)` then you'll get back a string which has had everything that matches the given pattern removed. You could then tokenize this string (ie. call `split` on it) to get a list of words that don't match the pattern.

Comment: Looks like Berry beat me to it though!